# How to reduce the node of the leaves of the jqTree to the text Length

Tags: jquery, jqtree

In the jQtree plugin by mBraak which I am exploring and using recently. Found that the nodes by default take the full length of the parent container. So adding

```
ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-element {
    cursor: pointer;
    *display:inline-block;*
}
```

in the jqTree.css file will fix this. But the drag and drop is still active despite this fix. Above fixes the long width node leaves.

Answer (score 0):

In the jQtree plugin by mBraak which I am exploring and using recently. Found that the nodes by default take the full length of the parent container. So adding

```
ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-element {
    cursor: pointer;
    **display:inline-block;**
}
```

in the jqTree.css file will fix this. But the drag and drop is still active despite this fix. Above fixes the long width node leaves.